# sql UPDATE row::leave present value if input empty

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm new to this and I'm not sure if this is a php question or a sql, but I have a form with no required fields where when submit it updates columns in a database row. Currently, when the form is submitted if an input is left empty it updates the corresponding column with the empty space and erasing the value that was once there. What I am trying to figure out is how to make it so upon form submission, if an input value is empty, it doesnt update the database column.

```
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    $user = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $signature = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['signature']);
    $skype = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['skype']);
    $facebook = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['facebook']);

    $insert = $mysqli->query("
    UPDATE users 
    SET u_signature='$signature', u_skype='$skype', u_facebook='$facebook' 
    WHERE u_name='$user'
    ") or die ($mysqli->error);
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: wow i got a LOT of updating to do... thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

    $user = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    $signature = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['signature']);
    $skype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['skype']);
    $facebook = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['facebook']);
    if(!empty($signature)){
     $update_fields[] = "u_signature='$signature'";
    }
    if(!empty($skype)){
     $update_fields[] = "u_skype='$skype'";
    }
    if(!empty($facebook)){
     $update_fields[] = "u_facebook='$facebook'";
    }
    if(count($update_fields) > 0){
      $nonempty_fields = implode(", ", $update_fields);
      $insert = mysql_query("
      UPDATE users 
      SET $nonempty_fields
      WHERE u_name='$user'
      ") or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else{
     echo "must not update the db because all required fields are empty";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Please edit it for your use, this is just a pattern for education purpose.

Comment: Is this what they call "Prepared statements" ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the old data in the inputs by default, so if no data is changed, it's just the old data inserted again. Otherwise:

```
$q_vars = "UPDATE users SET ";
if(!empty($signature))
{
$q_vars .= "signature = $signature ";
}
```

but with an array + foreach to add the commas if its not last.