# Update table set only column which have input

Tags: php, mysql

Hi there here is my problem I'm working on app which update data to db. My problem is when I send new data to db if the input is empty it overwrites the existing data in table with 0. Only if I have some value, in my case numbers in inputs it updates correctly.

How to check empty inputs i don't send them?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "medvedgrad";

// First we create the connection
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=".$mysql_host .";dbname=".$mysql_database .";charset=utf8", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$zm = $data->zlatni_medvjed;
$ck = $data->crna_kraljica;
$gv = $data->gricka_vjestica;
$dk = $data->dva_klasa;
$fk = $data->fakin;

// Then we prepare, and execute the query
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `stanje_piva` SET `zlatni_medvjed`=`zlatni_medvjed`+:zm, `crna_kraljica`=`crna_kraljica`+:ck, `gricka_vjestica`=`gricka_vjestica`+:gv, `dva_klasa`=`dva_klasa`+:dk,`fakin`=`fakin`+:fk WHERE `id`=1");


 $stmt->execute(array("zm" => $zm, "ck" => $ck, "gv" => $gv, "dk" => $dk, "fk" =>   $fk));
 ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql UPDATE row::leave present value if input empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677362/sql-update-rowleave-present-value-if-input-empty)

Comment: I need to save `0 (0 as an integer)` to db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to include only not-empty values to the array and update only those.

```
$updateArray = array();
$sqlString = "Update `stanje_piva` SET ";

foreach(['zm' => $zm, 'ck' => $ck, 'gv' => $gv, 'dk' => $dk, 'fk' => $fk] as $key => $value){

    // add to updateArray ONLY IF NOT EMPTY
    if($value != ''){
        // add key/value to updateArray
        array_push($updateArray, $key => $value);

        // append key/value to sql string
        switch($key){
            case 'zm': 
                $sqlString .= "`zlatni_medvjed`=`zlatni_medvjed`+:zm, ";
                break;
            case 'ck': 
                $sqlString .= "`crna_kraljica`=`crna_kraljica`+:ck, ";
                break;
            case 'gv': 
                $sqlString .= "`gricka_vjestica`=`gricka_vjestica`+:gv, ";
                break;
            case 'dk': 
                $sqlString .= "`dva_klasa`=`dva_klasa`+:dk, ";
                break;
            case 'fk': 
                $sqlString .= "`fakin`=`fakin`+:fk, ";
                break;
        }
    }
}

// remove last ', ' from sqlQuery
$sqlQuery = substr($sqlQuery, 0, strlen($sqlQuery)-2);

// add Where clause
$sqlQuery .= " WHERE `id`=1";

// prepare
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sqlQuery);

// execute
$stmt->execute($updateArray);
```

edit: forgot to prepare stmt, added that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($zm) && !empty($ck) && !empty($gv) && !empty($dk) && !empty($fk)) {
    $stmt->execute(array("zm" => $zm, "ck" => $ck, "gv" => $gv, "dk" => $dk, "fk" =>   $fk));
}
```

Comment: A code only answer doesn't carry much value. Consider including some explanation about what your posted code does and how it solves the issue.

Comment: I need to save `0 (0 as an integer)` to db